# JQuery - Which events do pop up windows use?

Tags: jquery, html, popup, modal-dialog

I am developing a webpage with a select option that does not use the native-menu.

[image: When you load the page]

When the screen is large enough, and you click the select option, the pop up appears like so:

[image]

However, when you pull up the console (F12 in Chrome) or some mobile devices, and click the select option, the pop up goes modal (fullscreen)

[image]

**QUESTION** What are the events that are called when each is closed (in both the 2nd and 3rd picture posted above)? I have a gut feeling it is not the same..

Might one be

```
$(select[name='select_menu']).???
```

Below is the code for the select tag I have, as well as some options. This is all contained in a form..

```
<form name="form_header" id="form_header" data-id="form_header">
```

---

```
<select name="select_menu" id="select_menu" form="form_header" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false"data-rel="dialog" data-placeholder="true" placeholder="student_id">
    <option>Search By:</option>
    <option for="form_header" id="1" data-num="1" value="student_id">Student ID</option>
    <option for="form_header" id="2" data-num="2" value="parking_permit">Parking Permit</option>
    <option for="form_header" id="3" data-num="3" value="license_plate">License Plate</option>
    <option for="form_header" id="4" data-num="4" value="first_name">First Name</option>
    <option for="form_header" id="5" data-num="5" value="last_name">Last Name</option>
                    <!--Add more options here if need be-->
</select>
```